British TV show 999
Hi my question is regarding British TV show 999 hosted by Michael Buerk (or at least I think).
One episode many moonlights ago told a story of a group of classroom students who went cave diving in bogs. As they reached a point where they had to go under water a few seconds and individually to get to the other side of a wall, one boy went a bit too deep and got himself trapped in a totally new cave. They found out he was missing right at the end by they managed to rescue him.
Can anyone tell me whether this was an episode of 999, if so then what episode this was it and if there's any other news about this incident on line?

It's outside our scope to do the research for you as to whether there's any other info on the web but my answer should make it easy for you to do the search yourself.

It looks like this episode about Dido's Cave but the video doesn't say which episode it's from.
The part you're talking about is explained at around 3:50.



It occurred in 1982, apparently and the names are in the video, so if you're looking for news about it, that info should be plenty for you.
The kid's name is Phillip Gregory.

Well done Cat
